# MongoDB query issue with date range

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm trying to execute simple query using morphia over MongoDB, in my local machine its working fine but in another machine its not working,
This is my query

```
List<Ino> ino = ds.find(Ino.class).field("g_id").hasAnyOf(gId).field("iDate").greaterThanOrEq(stDate)    
.field("iDate").lessThan(inoEnd).asList()
```

stDate and inoEnd are

```
Tue Jan 01 16:36:37 IST 2013 , Wed Jan 30 16:36:37 IST 2013
```

Above query returns empty list, but when i try it using following quires it work fine

```
List<Ino> ino = ds.find(Ino.class).field("g_id").hasAnyOf(gId).field("iDate").greaterThanOrEq(stDate).asList()
```

this returns

```
    [Ino(_id=926, g_id=27, iDate=Mon Jan 14 00:00:00 IST 2013), 
     Ino(_id=1026, g_id=27, iDate=Thu Feb 14 00:00:00 IST 2013), 
     Ino(_id=1110, g_id=27, iDate=Thu Mar 14 00:00:00 IST 2013)]
```

and then i tried

```
    List<Ino> ino = ds.find(Ino.class).field("g_id").hasAnyOf(gId).field("iDate").lessThan(inoEnd).asList()
```

this returns

```
   [Ino(_id=926, g_id=27, iDate=Mon Jan 14 00:00:00 IST 2013)]
```

Only different in my local and other machine is data representation
This is how my local collections is

```
{ "_id" : 926, "className" : "test", "g_id" : 27, "iDate" : ISODate("2013-01-14T18:30:00Z")}
```

But in other machine collection is

```
{ "_id" : 926, "className" : "test", "g_id" : 27, "iDate" : "Mon Jan 14 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"}
```

So what can be the reason for that above first query result is empty ?

Comment: My local mongo version is MongoDB shell version: 1.6.3      
Other machine(which is not working one) mongo version is MongoDB shell version: 1.6.5 , can it be a issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i overcome with a solution but still i don't know what was wrong, I updated monogDB version to 2.4.4 from 2.1, then everything works as i expected

Thanks